# cake php multiple pagination on same view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to show two listings from two differant models on the same ctp file.
How can i set two pagination without using ajax?
Its hardly requirement for my project.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's scheduled to be possible in CakePHP 3.0 stable; but is not possible with the _core_ pagination component/helper in earlier versions.

Comment: Ajax only (will be much much easy and reliable). because pagination component uses the variables from url. if you read the url you will understand the concept. Don't waste your time on solving this by pagination component. I believe even if CakePhp 10 come can't create this because this is some thing illogical

Comment: @IsaacRajaei why do you think `/new?pagePosts=1&pageUsers=3` is illogical? It's a [long standing request to be able to do this](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/1731) - hence it'll almost certainly be possible in 3.0 stable.

Comment: if you play around with arguments. even then the first pagination will be back to the first status. Unless you make a long dirty url full of arguments.

Comment: @IsaacRajaei persisting all pagination arguments is part of that task, the url would only be as long as is necessary - such as the above example. In any event: when I've finished implementing it there's nothing forcing you to use it =).

Comment: looking forward to it mate

Comment: @AD7six - CakePHP is currently at 3.1.2 as I write this.  It does not appear from the documentation that it is yet possible - has the feature been implemented yet to allow multiple paginators in a view without resorting to AJAX?

Comment: @DJFar no, nobody found the time/interest to implement it so it's not possible with the core component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply not possible to use two paginators, with different models or with the same model. You need to use ajax pagination. The CakePHP standard does not allow two paginators on the same view.

Comment: If Ajax is only solution for that. then can you provide a code of ajax?

Comment: Hi! You have to call by ajax requests than you have to tell your respose al of your "a" tag need to ajax call. Here is an example:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/9c5nH/2/)
In cakephp you have to tell your controller if ajax request is coming do not render default layout it have to render an ajax layout wich contains only te controllers view without layout. Like this:
'  if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            $this->autoLayout = false;
      
            $this->layout = "ajax";
        } '