# Different current page in one controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using pagination on my CakePHP page and it works well, but I have a few pages generated by different functions in one controller file and there is an cumbersome issue.

Let's assume I've got two tables with hundreds of entries, which my paginators divide and display 15 of entries on one page:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'Table1' => Array(
        'order' => array('Table1.id' => 'desc'),
        'limit' => 15
    ),
    'Table2' => Array(
        'order' => array('Table2.id' => 'asc'),
        'limit' => 15
    )
);
```

And functions in this controller file:

```
public function showTable1() {
    $this->set('table', $this->paginate('Table1'));
}
public function showTable2() {
    $this->set('table', $this->paginate('Table2));
}
```

When I go to the next page while displaying "Table 1", I go to the next page and it works well. But when I open another page with "Table 2" generated by another function from the same controller file, it unfortunately also goes to the second page.

What should I do to have different "pages indicators"? I mean, when I go to the third page on "Table 1", I don't want to go to the third page when I go to "Table 2".

Thanks in advance. I hope I presented my problem clearly.

Comment: The `table` view variable that's set, gets overridden.

Comment: Ditto @LozCheroneツ : You're overwriting the variable; only one value can be held by a single variable (`$table`) in the view. Also see: ["cakephp - cake php multiple pagination on same view"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755546/cake-php-multiple-pagination-on-same-view).

Comment: But I don't use these two Controllers on one view. They are used separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of setting the pagination options on the top of the controller, try deleting that `public $paginate` and setting all the options inside action, like this (and in the similar way for the second action)

```
public function showTable1() {
    $options = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Table1.id' => whatever
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Table1.id'
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Table1.id' => 'DESC'
        ),
        'limit' => 15
    );

    $this->Paginator->settings = $options;
    $table = $this->Paginator->paginate('Table1');

    $this->set(compact('table'));
}
```

Comment: that works, but whenever I go on Table1 or Table2 page, I start viewing data from the first sub page of the table. I thought that thanks to CakePHP paginator, I should be starting the view from the last visited sub page. I mean now the code lost the function of remembering the last visited sub page.